# µ and é in namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces

We have developed a c# program. The program is distributed in Europe without problem on misc hardware configurations. Some of the namespaces in our program contains a 'µ' or a 'é' character. When deploying our program on 'non-european' ie China or some US systems a problem occurs somewhere in the process the 'µ' is changed into 'Âµ' causing lots of problems. What is causing this problem and how can we work around it (preferably without changing the name of the namespace)

**edit 2015.08.07**

Thanks all for your comments, but to clarify: the source files are not distributed as such. The program is compiled to an exe and then distributed using nsis. Source control is done using SVN. How can I verify the presence of the BOM in my source files ?

Comment: What do you mean by "somewhere in the process"? What *exactly* are you observing? How are you deploying? What sort of program is this? What encoding are you using in your source code - and is that source code being rebuilt as part of deployment? There's way too little information here to help you.

Comment: check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539564/special-characters-in-a-namespace Also keep in mind that just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean that you *should*

Comment: Whomever is loading this source code file is not getting the utf-8 BOM character that is always inserted at the start of the file.  So his text editor is reading file with the default code page which makes the utf-8 encoding visible.  How that BOM disappeared is hard to guess from a distance.  Some source control systems, particularly the ones that have a Unix background, tend to strip it off.  Or maybe he's using a text editor that completely ignores it.  Just verify that the BOM is present in your version of the file, from there it is no longer your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Either you or the recipient or both are using a character encoding other than UTF-8.

People shouldn't do that, but they do.

Some tools will default to a legacy encoding unless you include a BOM at the start of each file, so include a BOM at the start of each file.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting a difference in the character sets used by the different systems.  Your software was probably running on systems assuming ISO-8859, most often used in European languages, while the Chinese and US systems you are encountering are probably using the Universal Character Set (ISO/IEC 10646).  The mapping between the two is not a simple 1-to-1, so you run into the problems you are having.  W3.org has a good article on this topic at http://www.w3.org/International/articles/definitions-characters/

Pay special attention to the sections on "Character sets, coded character sets, and encodings", and "The Document Character Set".  If this is a web app, "The HTTP Header" might be particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer. However I want to point out that this might be an encoding problem but this can happen on the same system and show up only when running code that (guess here) reads a byte at a time, as opposed to explicitly reading text of a particular encoding.

I have a C program (32 bit if that matters) which reads in a file using fgetc and saves characters to be used as "illegal" characters in names. It isn't fancy, just to prevent a few ascii characters from coming in accidentally, like an ' (apostrophe) in the name of a thing/object/label.  Some one asked me to test µ (mu, appears as single character in this interface to stackoverflow).  I generated this (without examining underlying encoding in MS Word) using Insert-Symbol in MS Word. I cut it from MS Word and inserted it into a text file using Notepad++.  In Notepad++ and MS Word, it seems to be the same symbol.  BUT fgetc (taking one int or char, however you like to think of it) at a time, sees in my debug output for a test case:

```
About to check for illegal characters in =>NameOfItemÂµ<=
Illegal character =>Â<= was found. Illegal characters are: '`Âµ
Illegal character =>µ<= was found. Illegal characters are: '`Âµ
```

I am compiling with Visual C++ Express 2013.

I'm happy it catches the illegal characters, and hope this isn't just noise to readers of this topic.